# Calculating Rounds for SHA Iterations in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, cryptography

I'm dealing with the issue of having to figure out a good number of iterations to use for SHA on an android device, without impacting user experience. The difficulty is that since I'm supporting all the way back to Android 2.x, I can't set a hard and fast number of rounds to use since the difference of computational power between the last couple of generations of phones is huge, and either the number would be too low and be insecure, or it would be too high and take lower end phones much too long to compute.

I'm attempting to use a thread at first time startup to calculate the time that increasing number of rounds will take in order to find a good number on a per phone basis (ergo start at a baseline number of rounds, if the time is under threshold, bump up the number and check if the time is still under threshold. Repeat until threshold is exceeded). The issue is that I use system time to see how long the calculation ends up taking, but context switching is artificially inflating the time value and forcing the analysis to end early before a fraction of the phone's cpu power is tapped.

Is there a way I can get around this, without forcing the user to wait as I run this analysis on the main UI thread for a first time setup?

Edit: At least I figure that it is context switching that is screwing up the timing. When I run this on the main UI thread, the iteration analysis code runs as would be expected, with no weird hiccups in how long the SHA hashing takes. When run on a separate thread, it'll be fine for the first couple steps of the iteration analysis, and then suddenly will experience a huge hiccup (most of the time) in how long the hash took, and prematurely end the method.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I realized I was over thinking the problem. In an attempt to catch when context switching was throwing my problem, I attempted to set an upper threshold that basically said "if the milliseconds recorded is bigger than X, then a context switch probably occurred, so ignore and continue." This didn't work, because sometimes the context switch would push it just over the lower threshold. 
I just realized I should be comparing the difference between the last try and the current try. Since the value used to increment the number of rounds is small, if the difference is greater than about 70 - 80 ms, I know an abnormality occurred, and that I should ignore it and continue.

Comment: Glad you got it solved, but please bear in mind that these kind of constructs are usually only used for password based key derivation (functions). And in that case you only need to heed the amount of computer power that *an attacker* can harness. You are better off strengthening the password (or the security of the system) instead.

Comment: I completely understand your point, but unfortunately I am restricted by UX requirements as to how far I can take these things.